# Is there a mistake in a Proposition (EGA I, Chap-I, (9.1.2) about affine morphism?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

Soit $f:X\rightarrow$ un morphisme affine. Pour tout ouvert $U\subset Y $, le morphisme $f^{-1}(U)\rightarrow U$, restriction de f, est affine.

Translation: Let $f:X\rightarrow$ an affine  morphism. For all open $U\subset Y $, the morphism $f^{-1}(U)\rightarrow U$, restriction of  f, is affine.

***Don't we need here $U$ to be affine also in $Y$?***

This is from EGA-I Springer Verlag 1971 Edition

Comment: No. A morphism $f:X\to Y$ is affine if for an affine cover $\{U_\}$ of $Y$, $f^{-1}(U_i)$ is affine for all $i$ and equivalently, $f^{-1}(U)$ is affine for any affine open $U$ of $Y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\{V_\alpha\}_\alpha$ be an affine cover of $Y$ with affine preimages, and denote $\varphi_\alpha\colon \mathcal{O}_Y(V_\alpha) \to \mathcal{O}_X(f^{-1}(V_\alpha))$ to be the corresponding map on the coordinate rings of $V_\alpha$ and $f^{-1}(V_\alpha)$.

Then, $U$ is covered by $\{U \cap V_\alpha\}_\alpha$, and each $U \cap V_\alpha$ can be covered by open sets $\{D_{V_\alpha}(h_\beta)\}_{\beta}$ that are distinguished in $V_\alpha$. These open sets $\{D_{V_\alpha}(h_\beta)\}_{\alpha,\beta}$ form an affine open cover of $U$. The preimages of the $D_{V_\alpha}(h_\beta)$ are distinguished in $f^{-1}(V_\alpha)$; more precisely, they are of the form $D_{f^{-1}(V_\alpha)}(\varphi_\alpha(h_\beta))$, hence are affine.

Comment: To cover $U\cap V_\alpha$ by $\{D_{V_\alpha}(h_\beta)\}_{\beta}$ich are also open affine in $V_\alpha$, one needs $U$ also to be affine open, is not it?

Comment: No; $U$ is open in $Y$, hence $U \cap V_\alpha$ is open in $V_\alpha$. Then, the distinguished open sets $D_{V_\alpha}(h)$ form a basis of $V_\alpha$, and so you can write $U \cap V_\alpha$ as a union of sets of the form $D_{V_\alpha}(h_\beta)$.

I'll also add that Mohan's comment is another proof: using what Vakil calls the affine communication lemma, you can show that being an affine morphism is the same as asking that $f^{-1}(V)$ is affine for all open affines $V \subset Y$. But open affines in $U$ are also open in $Y$, and are still affine.

Comment: One has to prove that $U$ can be covered by open affines in $U$ in so that the inverse image of each that is affine. Now $\{D_{V_\alpha}(h_\beta)\}_{\beta}$ is distinguished in $V_\alpha$ but unless you take $U$ to be affine, it is not clear why $\{D_{V_\alpha}(h_\beta)\}_{\beta}$ is affine inside $U$ (which is required in order to say the restriction map is affine.)

Comment: One needs to cover $U$ by open affines of $U$, where $\{D_{V_\alpha}(h_\beta)\}_{\beta}$ is distinguished in $V_\alpha$ but not in $U$. Hence, we don't know whether it is affine.

Comment: In short what I want to say $\{D_{V_\alpha}(h_\beta)\}_{\alpha,\beta}$ forms an open cover of $U$, but it need not be an 'affine' open cover of $U$.

Comment: Each $D_{V_\alpha}(h_\beta)$ is affine, since it's a distinguished open set in an affine scheme. I don't know what you mean by being "affine inside $U$"; being affine doesn't depend on what scheme you are a subscheme of. If you really want to have distinguished open sets of affine subsets of $U$, you can do the following: choose an affine cover $\{W_\gamma\}$ of $U$. Each $W_\gamma$ is covered by some collection of $V_\alpha$'s, and their intersections can be covered by a set of distinguished opens that are both distinguished…

Comment: …in $W_\gamma$ and in $V_\alpha$ by the affine communication lemma I mentioned before.

Comment: Thanx, I got confused. I have understood it now.